# categorizing items in a list based on another list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want to categorize elements inside the **items** list based on the **category** list.

```
category = [[1, "grape fruit"], [2, "orange fruit"], [3, "orange cookies"], [4, "pineapple pie"], [5, "strawberry"]]

items = ["grape juice - 1L", "Grape syrup - 500gr", "strawberry cookies 5's -2packs", "orange juice - 500gr", "orange cookies 10's 1 pack", "orange pudding - 1pcs", "pies - 1box"]
```

**This is the result that I want:**

```
result = [1, 1, 5, 2, 3, 2, 4]
```

I wonder if this is possible to be done with for loop, or if there is any way to categorize it.

Thank you

Comment: How are you looking to match the item in items with the one in category. Is it fixed or random like in your example.

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by fixed or random. Would you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Well an easy approach for this type of problems is the fuzzy matching. There are many libraries to do fuzzymatches in python so that you don't have to write one yourself.

An example using `fuzzywuzzy` package is given below.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
category = [[1, "grape fruit"], [2, "orange fruit"], [3, "orange cookies"], [4, "pineapple pie"], [5, "strawberry"]]
items = ["grape juice - 1L", "Grape syrup - 500gr", "strawberry cookies 5's -2packs", "orange juice - 500gr",
         "orange cookies 10's 1 pack", "orange pudding - 1pcs", "pies - 1box"]
result = []
fuzzy_index = {cat[0]: cat[1] for cat in category}
for item in items:
    matcher = " ".join(item.split(" ")[:2])
    val = process.extractOne(matcher, fuzzy_index)[2]
    result.append(val)

print(result)
```

Result was:

```
[1, 1, 5, 2, 3, 2, 4]
```

This was an approach based on this sample set. You can use fuzzymatching or nltk packages to build a matching index depending on the complexity of the problem.

Comment: Wow Kris, you are super helpful, thank you so much!! Hope some day I can be as good as you ! Awesome work!!!

Comment: If it worked for you You can accept the answer and upwote, so some one else also will get benefit :-)